# What is the meaning of $\nabla _{\mu}\nabla _{\nu}\phi(r)$ in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory, differentiation, curvature

I know the covariant derivative of a tensor  is
$$\nabla_{\mu} V_{\nu}=\partial_\mu V_\nu-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}V_{\lambda}$$
Now I want to obtain  $\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\Phi(x)$ where  $\Phi(x)$ is a scalar field. I consider $ V_\nu=\nabla_{\nu}\Phi(x)$ and then
$$\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\Phi(x)=\partial_\mu \partial_\nu \Phi(x)-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}\partial_\lambda \Phi(x)$$

Is this correct? If so, how can I interpret $\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\Phi(x)$?

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: I can not consider$∇μ∇νΦ(x)=∂μ∂νΦ(x)$?can I?

Comment: No. The first derivative $\nabla_\nu$ is acting on a scalar so we can replace $\nabla_\nu \to \partial_\nu$, but the second one is acting on a tensor.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: The question in your title is different from the one you're asking. Do you want to know how to interpret $\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi(r)$ or do you want to if your last statement is correct?

Comment: yes, could you please  interpret it ?